# Slow population of a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm still very new to R and am noticing a very slow load time for the population of a dataframe

For my dataset I'm wanting to load the dataframe per row in the dataset, based on the value in column $population

It should end up with around 700,000 rows but after 10 minutes processing it's only loaded about 77,000 which appears really really slow

Code as per below

```r
df <- data.frame(Ints=integer())

for(i in 1:nrow(popDemo)) {
    row <- popDemo[i,]       
        
    # Use a while value to loop
    j <- 1
    while (j <= row$population) {
       df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- row$age
       j = j+1
      
}
}
```

Any guidance greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: I suggest you give a small sample of `popDemo` and your expected output given that input. I'd think 10 rows or so input should suffice, but that might be influenced by what you need done.

Comment: Many Thanks for your response r2evans. I did some referencing in other threads to the list option, just wasn't sure on how to apply the syntax, so this is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a simple `popDemo`,

```r
popDemo <- data.frame(population=c(3,5), age=c(1,10))
```

Your code produces

```r
df <- data.frame(Ints=integer())
for (i in 1:nrow(popDemo)) {
  row <- popDemo[i,]       
  # Use a while value to loop
  j <- 1
  while (j <= row$population) {
    df[nrow(df) + 1,] <- row$age
    j = j+1
  }
}
df
#   Ints
# 1    1
# 2    1
# 3    1
# 4   10
# 5   10
# 6   10
# 7   10
# 8   10
```

This can be done *much faster* in one step:

```r
data.frame(Ints = rep(popDemo$age, times = popDemo$population))
#   Ints
# 1    1
# 2    1
# 3    1
# 4   10
# 5   10
# 6   10
# 7   10
# 8   10
```

If by chance you have more columns, and you're hoping to just repeat them, an alternative implementation that is not just one column.

```r
popDemo <- data.frame(population=c(3,5), age=c(1,10), ltr=c("a","b"))
popDemo[ rep(seq_len(nrow(popDemo)), times = popDemo$population), ]
#     population age ltr
# 1            3   1   a
# 1.1          3   1   a
# 1.2          3   1   a
# 2            5  10   b
# 2.1          5  10   b
# 2.2          5  10   b
# 2.3          5  10   b
# 2.4          5  10   b
```

Comment: Thanks again...really really helpful, performance is nothing short of blistering